# VSCode Latex Workshop's auto surrounding selected text stop working after updating VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, latex, vscode-extensions

Until recently, when I select text and then type `@(` or `\section`, etc., the selected text reappear insides `\left( <selected text> \right)` or `\section{ <selected text>}`.
However, this stopped working after I updated VSCode.
I can't find any information about this issue, so I wonder if anyone know the answer why this happens or know how to fix this?

I tried revert back to Latex Workshop in several previous versions but it doesn't help. Also, I haven't edit any setting that I know of.

Answer (score 0):

I just found a solution: I revert back to VSCode 1.72 and it works fine now.
It seems that the problem stems from this issue https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/165746 from the VSCode side.